# How to kill off these processes?

Tags: centos, process, apache-httpd, kill

**Problem**

I have by mistake initiated a `PHP background process script` that calls itself and has now created an infinite loop of calling itself over and over. It currently sends an email to my Gmail account, and I get tons of e-mails.
The PHP script uses cURL to call itself recursively (using the PHP exec() function).

When I run `ps faux` I see a tremendous amount of Apache child processes, and I can't seem to kill those off.

**What I've tried**

- I've tried stop these processes with `kill <pid>` but it doesn't seem to help - new ones pops up after this
- I've tried killing these processes with `killall -9 httpd`, which kills all these processes, but it also terminates the main httpd WebServer process itself, and when I start that process again all of these looping php/apache processes are back.
- Removed the PHP script itself completely from the WebServer, does not affect this at all
- Restarted the VPS

Any ideas in what to try next?

---

**UPDATE: Here is the code:**

example.com -> /var/www/site1/index.php:

```
<?php

require_once "processor.php";

<html>
...
```

/var/www/site1/processor.php:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['test]) && $_POST['test] == 1) {
  // send an e-mail to my Gmail account
}

run_background_process('example.com', 'test=1');
    
function run_background_process($url, $params) {

  // do a normal cURL POST
  $cmd = 'curl -X POST ';
  // append the URL to the script
  $cmd .= $url;
  // add any variables that needs to be passed to the target script
  $cmd .= ' -d "' . $params . '"';
  // run it in the background so it does not affect page load
  $cmd .= " > /dev/null 2>&1 &"; 
  // execute
  exec($cmd, $output, $exit); 
  return $exit == 0;

}
```

---

**UPDATE: Additional things I've now tried:**

- reset Apache and PHP configurations (removed all Apache VHosts)
- restarted the VPS multiple times

Nothing has killed these stubborn processes off so far

---

**UPDATE: This is how the process table looks like when running `ps faux`:**

```
root      1305  1.0  1.1  39444 12096 ?        Ss   13:38   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    1307  0.0  0.5  39444  6192 ?        S    13:38   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    ...   ...  ...  .....  .... .        .    .....   ....  \_ /usr/sbin/httpd
```

It's that second line and downards I want to terminate once and for all.

---

**UPDATE**: Question: Perhaps these re-occuring httpd tasks coming from a cache location of some sort? Meaning these tasks exist / are stacked up in some cache/tmp environment?

---

**UPDATE**: Here is the result of `netstat -tlpan` (masked out the IPs with x)

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      900/sendmail
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.x:8000                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      22457/httpd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7648                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      554/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1345                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      949/perl
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      836/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      22457/httpd
tcp        0     64 x.x.x.x:7648                x.x.x.x:56524       ESTABLISHED 27410/sshd
tcp        0      0 :::7648                     :::*                        LISTEN      554/sshd
```

---

## UPDATE: Could this perhaps be a bug in Apache / httpd itself? As killing the Apache service once should kill off all child processes for good.

Comment: You say removing the script doesn't help, I would expect that to be the case, what was the php script designed to do?

Comment: It was just a bad php script test on my part -- basically it's designed to check a folder, and if that folder contains any files, move those files to a different location. I'm gonna update the question above with the code

Comment: And after removing script how do you know it's still running? Those processes might be orphaned from that original script parent process.

Comment: When I check the process list with ps fuax I see lots and lots of httpd child processes, and also I get hundreds upon hundreds of e-mals to my Gmail account (I didn't include the mail code in the example code above)

Comment: Ok run `ps aux | grep Z` to spot any zombies!

Comment: When I run this, I get: 

USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
camursm  1170  0.0  0.0   5568   752 pts/0    S+   13:19   0:00 grep Z

<------ is this normal?

Comment: Yes it is that's for the grep command you just ran! And we don't see any zombies there either! And you say a restart doesn't help too?

Comment: That's correct. Really strange

Comment: Perhaps these re-occuring httpd tasks coming from a cache location of some sort? Meaning these tasks exist / are stacked up in some cache/tmp environment?

Comment: Please add the output of `netstat -tlpan` (as root) or examine it for yourself to check whether these are many incoming connections (probably not).

Comment: @Ned64 Thanks for chiming in, I just ran `netstat -tlpan` as root and posted the result above.

Comment: OK, so there are not many external connection attempts and we can rule out a DDoS-like situation. (Assuming here you have done the `netstat` during the problematic situation!)

Comment: @Ned64 Good point

Answer (score 0):

**Correct your code:**

Looking at your code (thanks for supplying it now) you seem to be missing an `else` - depending on what you wish to do, of course, as we have no requirement specification.

If you only wish to spawn 1 background process, try this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['test']) && $_POST['test'] == 1) {
  // send an e-mail to my Gmail account
}
else
  run_background_process('example.com', 'test=1');

(...)
```

Otherwise you will call all of your code again after sending each e-mail.

(Your original code also contained too few single quotes `´` in the `if` statement which I assume are there in your file, just not on your question - unless php is even more generous with its syntax than I thought.)

**Workaround to stop the spawned processes:**

Try this to kill

```
ps aux | grep -w httpd | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs --no-run-if-empty kill -KILL
```

or to suspend (stop) the processes:

```
ps aux | grep -w httpd | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs --no-run-if-empty kill -STOP
```

Comment: Many thanks for the idea. I tried the first command, it successfully kills the processes, but that includes the main Apache/httpd service itself. And when I start the service back with "service httpd start", a big pile of httpd child processes re-appears

Comment: I've also tried targeting and killing subproceses specifically, with "pkill -u apache", but as soon as I've get the processes purged, new ones appear

Comment: Maybe this could be solved if I purge and reinstall the Apache/HTTPD service altogether?

Comment: Or, perhaps these re-occuring httpd tasks coming from a cache location of some sort? Meaning these tasks exist / are stacked up in some `cache/tmp` environment?

Comment: Normally `apache` by itself spawns worker processes (and you can control the number of total/spare ones) but no php code is run without an external call. That is why I requested the `netstat` output.

Comment: What happens if you change the `apache` `Listen` port from 80 to something unorthodox, say 90 (possibly the same for 443)?

Comment: Aa make sense, thanks. I changed the `Listen port` of apache to `90`, and restarted the service - no change it seems

Comment: Many thanks for the code, this is what I was about to add to the code block to avoid the infinite loop, but I ran the script above prematurely by mistake.. and now I can't get it killed

Comment: After changing the code, even a reboot won't stop the spawning?

Comment: No the processes are back even the I change the script and reboot - it's super strange.  I've even tried removing the script altogether, even changing /var/www to /var/www2 to make sure nothing can initiate the script.. I'm leaning more and more towards this being some sort of bug with the Apache/httpd server itself. As killing the Apache service once should kill off all child processes for good.

Comment: Try clearing the apache `mod_cache` if it exists: Stop Apache, then `htcacheclean -v -a` to view and `htcacheclean -v -r -l0` to remove all of it.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion, however I don't use `mod_cache` at all.

Comment: Do you still have the problem? I know how I would look if I had access to the server but in these comments it takes so much time!